# Django send_mail "to_email" field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am having trouble getting the `to_email` field for the recipient.

Using Django 2.1 and sending an automatic email after a user signs up to a certain page.

Right now the email sends to `reciever@gmail.com` which is obviously incorrect.

It needs to send to whatever email was entered into the form.

I've tried changing to `to_email= request.POST['email']` and `to_email = form.cleaned_data['email']` but those don't work.

`to_email = form.cleaned_data['email']` gives the error

`TypeError at /users/list "to" argument must be a list or tuple`

Then changing it to

`to_email = form.cleaned_data['email',]`

gives the error

`KeyError at /users/list ('email',)`

Can someone help me?

views.py

```
def list_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ListForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f"signed up!")
            subject = "Yay."
            html_message = render_to_string('mail/mail_template.html', {'context': 'values'})
            plain_message = strip_tags(html_message)
            from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            to_email = ['receiver@gmail.com',]
            html_message.content_subtype = "html"
            send_mail( subject, plain_message, from_email, to_email, html_message=html_message )
            return redirect('landing')
```

forms.py

```
class ListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)


class Meta:
    model = List
    fields = ['email']
```

Comment: Doesn't work *how*? What happens?

Comment: it will always send email to the above mentioned email id as the same is hard-coded there `to_email = ['receiver@gmail.com',]`

Comment: @DanielRoseman I get an error that `form.cleaned_data` is not a tuple so I added a comma after `['email'],` then I get KeyError at `/users/list
('email',)`

Comment: Please show the exact code you used and the full error.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have added it above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error tells you exactly what is wrong: `"to" argument must be a list or tuple`. So, put it in a list or tuple.

```
to_email = (form.cleaned_data['email'],)
```